# NeDB Update does not work

Tags: nedb

With NeDB the first statement will update the data correctly, but the second (using the doc value itself as key(and yes docs[i].ID is '2013000060')
won't work - even the result of the update function tells me that 1 row was changed.

```
1. oDB.update({ MYID: '2013000060' }, { $set: { "PAGE": 2 }}, ...
2. oDB.update({ MYID: docs[i].ID}, {$set: {"PAGE": 2}}, ...
```

Some ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Take in account that [updates](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb#updating-documents) in NeDB work asynchronously.

Anything you want to do after updating an object (and relying on that updated values) should be done inside the `callback` function you pass to the `.update()` call.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around with NeDB datastore.js it turned out that this is sort of a weird timing problem.
The value is actually updated, but when a .find with a query was issued, the value was not yet persisted.
Anyway did I not go deeper to investigate the fact that using string literals yielded different results.

Answer (score 0):

Could you copy paste the exact code you're using, the expected results and the actual results ? From the look of it it seems like you are using synchronous code where you should use callbacks.